# SQL Server : determine the start/end times of a condition in logged data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Long story short I discovered an issue in a production stored procedure today that we use to log data coming from our PLCs, part of what the stored procedure does is insert rows to a logging table when a line goes down. When the stored procedure was logging these entries the correct start time wasn't being recorded, so I have all of my data except for the start times, if I can figure out how to determine that from the rest of our data I'll be OK.

We're running SQL Server 2012 and I've tried a handful of solutions mainly using `LAG()`, but I haven't been able to get the partition clause right.

sqlfiddle appears to be down for 2012 (I get a "can't connect to data source due to IOException" error on schema build) so unfortunately instead of a fiddle all I have is T-SQL for sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE LogData 
(
    LogID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL --ID Column
    ,LogTime DATETIME NOT NULL --TimeStamp Column
    ,LogLineID INT NOT NULL --Machine number
    ,LogCycles INT NOT NULL --Machine cycle count
    ,LogUptime decimal(5,2) --% Machine uptime across 5 min cycles
)

--"Downtime" is defined as [LogUptime] < 0.10
INSERT INTO LogData (LogTime, LogLineID, LogCycles, LogUptime)
VALUES
      ('01/01/2014 00:05:00', 1, 90, 0.85)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:05:00', 2, 100, 1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:10:00', 1, 50, 0.25)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:10:00', 2, 100, 1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:15:00', 1, 0, 0.01) --Start of Downtime...what I want to determine
     ,('01/01/2014 00:15:00', 2, 100, 1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:20:00', 1, 0, 0.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:20:00', 2, 100, 1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:25:00', 1, 0, 0.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:25:00', 2, 100, 1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:30:00', 1, 10, 0.04)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:30:00',2,100,1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:35:00',1,40,0.3) --End of Downtime...what I have
     ,('01/01/2014 00:35:00',2,100,1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:40:00',1,100,1.0)
     ,('01/01/2014 00:40:00',2,100,1.0)

--***Desired Result***
SELECT '01/01/2014 00:15:00' AS StartTime
    ,'01/01/2014 00:35:00' AS EndTime
    ,1 AS LineID
```

***EDIT*** - added partial query

I tried adding an additional column to the dataset in a sub-query denoting whether the line was down for that row or not, then partitioning by that column and using LAG() and also messed around with MIN/MAX in place of LAG. LAG just returns the time from the next row, and MIN returns the minimum value across the whole dataset ignoring the partition.

```
SELECT LogTime AS StartTime
,LAG(LogTime) OVER (PARTITION BY LogLineUp ORDER BY LogTime DESC) AS EndTime
,LogLineID
,LogUptime
,LogLineUp
FROM (
    SELECT LogTime
        ,LogLineID
        ,LogUptime
        ,CASE WHEN LogUptime < 0.1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS LogLineUp
    FROM LogData
    WHERE LogLineID = 1
) T2
```

Comment: I don't understand.  What's the logic that determines the start of a downtime?  Why is it the `'01/01/2014 00:15:00'` record and not some other record?  You're showing us data and not telling is why it has the meaning it does.  You don't list your partial query, either.

Comment: @BaconBits Sorry, I noted the downtime definition in an odd spot in the code-block, should have included it in the description above...downtime is defined as '[LineUptime] < 0.10' so it's based on the final column in the value sets.

Comment: @BaconBits Just added a partial query with explanation as well.

Comment: @motoxrdr21 Based on your sample data, I see that each LogLineID can have none or only one downtime period. Is it true?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov LogLineID is just a machine identifier so over time there are multiple periods for each machine(or Line) ID. The table we're actually looking at contains ongoing line performance data and I'm trying to recover the downtime start times based on the Uptime measurements that are recorded here.

Comment: @motoxrdr21, OK. So, your sample data is misleading. If it is possible to have several periods of downtime for the same LogLineID, then you'll have to use `LAG` / `LEAD` functions. Instead of your `LAG(LogTime)...` use `LAG(LogLineUp) OVER (PARTITION BY LogLineID ORDER BY LogTime)` and then find those rows that have LogLineUp <> `LAG(LogLineUp)...` OR LogLineUp <> `LEAD(LogLineUp)...`. I don't have SQL Server 2012 at hand, so I can't write the complete query for you.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov That worked like a charm, I just finished updating the data. I'll post the query in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @motoxrdr21 I think that it is better when you can solve the problem yourself, rather than taking the ready answer. I'd glad I could give you enough hints to work out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VladimirBaranov for fixing the LAG/LEAD portion of my query, giving me a working solution. Here's what I wound up with, I'm sure there's a more elegant approach than the nested sub-queries, but for a one time (hopefully) fix it worked for me.

Quick explanation of the query:

- T4 adds a column [LineUp] used as a flag to determine if the line was up or down
- T3 uses LAG() to pair the current row "LineUp" as [NewState] with the previous row's "LineUp" as [PreviousState] in order to determine at what rows there were up/down state changes.
- T2 uses LEAD() to combine current row time with the next row's time and has a where clause to exclude all rows that don't involve an up/down state change.
- The outer query selects only the periods of downtime by only including rows whose [PreviousState] was 'Up'.

I put the result in a temp table, then performed an update on the log entry start times by joining that table to the temp table using the LineID & EndTime columns.

```
    SELECT StartTime
            ,EndTime
            ,LineID
    FROM (
        SELECT LogTime AS StartTime
                ,LEAD(LogTime) OVER (ORDER BY LDTime) AS EndTime
                ,LogLineID AS LineID
                ,PreviousState
        FROM (
            SELECT LogTime
                    ,LAG(LineUp) OVER (PARTITION BY LogLineID ORDER BY LogTime) AS PreviousState
                    ,LineUp AS NewState
                    ,LogLineID
                    FROM (
                        SELECT LogTime
                                ,LogLineID
                            ,CASE WHEN LogUptime < 0.1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS LineUp
                        FROM LogData
                        WHERE LogLineID = 1
                    ) T4
                ) T3
        WHERE PreviousState <> NewState
        ) T2
    WHERE PreviousState = 1
```